# Displaying indexed png- files out of NSArray on the iphone screen

Tags: iphone, png, uiimageview, nsarray, addsubview

i like to create an artwork counter- display on an iphone, diplaying 0 to 9. The 10 digits are 10 png- files with the numbers 0 to 9 as their artwork content. The 10 png- files are implemented by using NSArray. Following you'll find the implementation- code:

```
zahlenArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-0.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-1.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-2.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-3.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-4.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-5.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-6.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-7.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-8.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"ziffer-9.png"],               
           nil];
```

As an index for the 10 digitis I use an integer variable, initializing with 0:

```
int counter = 0;
```

Furthermore I declare an UIImageview programmaticaly:

```
UIImageView *zahlenEinsBisNeun;
```

The implementation code for the UIImageview is:

```
zahlenEinsBisNeun = [UIImage alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 50, 200, 200)];

????????????????????????????????????????

[self.view addSubview:zahlenEinsBisNeun];
[zahlenEinsBisNeun release];
```

There, where you see the questionmarks, I don't know how to write the code, to retrieve my content artworks 0 to 9 from NSArray with the index "counter" and make it visible on my iphone screen by using .... addSubview:zahlenEinsBisNeun ...

Can anybody help???

My thanks for your support in advance

Thomas Hülsmann

Answer (score 1):

first of all instead of `zahlenEinsBisNeun = [UIImage alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 50, 200, 200)];`
 write

```
zahlenEinsBisNeun = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 50, 200, 200)];
```

then

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
      UIImage *tempImage = [zahlenArray objectAtIndex:i];
      [zahlenEinsBisNeun addSubview:tempImage];
}
[self.view addSubview:zahlenEinsBisNeun];
[zahlenEinsBisNeun release];
```

you'll need to adjust frame of each image before this...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to familiar with the iPhone SDK/image properties but surely you'd just

```
[zahlenArray objectAtIndex:counter]
```

to return the UI image you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understand you problem, but i think you should add only one UIImageView to subview and change IMAGE field from UIImageView

```
[self.view addSubview:zahlenEinsBisNeun];
```

and in timer or any thread (in other function) if you want change your images in this imageView:

```
zahlenEinsBisNeun.image = [zahlenArray objectAtIndex:counter]
```

regards,